# Does include and if slows down PHP?

Tags: php, performance

I'm writing some code for an assessment and trying to keep my page in various modules (like header, footer etc) that I include in a page to create the final version. I have some forms that root back to the same page and I have some ifs to catch if some session variables are set. Could that slow down the page for, lets say, 5-10 secs of loading a pretty simple page?

Could they have made something to the PHP interpreter from the department to keep some load off because of the simultaneous students uploading files, testing etc?

Thanks

Edit 1. Hmm. I just debugged the code by commenting out different stuff and I just realized that the slow part is a PHP function provided by the professor so not my bad... Thanks for your time...

Comment: How many If's you are going to do? Or how many includes? I think that in typical-large project there are something around 20-200 `include`'s and 5000-50000 `if`'s in whole project... Just guessing..

Comment: I'm talking about 5 ifs and 10 includes max :D

Comment: I think you're jumping to conclusions that "ifs" are to blame for your performance problem. A much better question to ask yourself (and ask us if necessary) is "What is causing my performance problems?" not "Is [some arbitrary thing] causing my performance problems?" Go through normal debugging procedures to narrow it down.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no way a couple of `include` and `if` statements are ever going to take 5-10 seconds to run, unless your server is from the Stone Age or *massively* overwhelmed with requests. Try to narrow down the problem to a specific bit of code by running some checks on how long different bits of code take to execute: get a timestamp before a given block of code and one after, and compare them to see how long execution of that block took. Also check with your sys admin whether there are any known issues with that server. If you are writing to or reading from a database, the problem could also be in your MySQL server being unable to process your queries quickly enough.

Comment: The MySQL seems fast since I query the whole tables for debugging purposes and put the results in simple tables. And that page that includes basically everything takes ms to load. The problem is that my main page takes forever to load for some reason...

Comment: I don't use pictures or anything. Only a logo of about 50kb and the rest is only buttons and text fields... It's a fairly naked page tbh...

Answer (score 3):

### Some tests...:

file `echo.php` contains:

```
<?php
echo "X";
?>
```

Testing performance `echo` vs. `include + echo`

```
1000 times `echo "X";`:             0.00019 secs.
1000 times `include "echo.php"`:    0.03694 secs.
```

However empty `echo.php` file included 1000 times took 0.05113 seconds...

### Then If:

```
1000000 times `if ($x = rand() && rand()) ;`:   0.72409 secs.
1000000 times `$x = rand() && rand();`: 0.76150 secs.
```

Comment: And I dont have too much computing power with `Pentium D 3.4GHz(*2cores)/2MB and 2GB DDR667`, so within any real server you can at least half those numbers :)

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? It would be nice if downvoters tell about their reasons so I can learn from my mistakes and maybe improve answers.

Answer (score 1):

No, not that much say it slows down the page by microseconds.

Actually in every language, if-elses slows down the process. But why to think such thing if your code does not work without them.

use them as you like. This is the nature of every programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if you'd notice any performance degradation on a reasonably simple project.

One way you could test whether there is an issue with what your doing might be to create a simple page without some of these headers and see how long that takes to load, then compare it with your project.
Another might be to try loading your project at home or somewhere away from school/college.

Answer (score -2):

it shouldn't be noticeable. but it has to do more work so it should be slower.
but 5-10 sec is a bit to much. i was thinking about the 1-2 area max.

Comment: 1-2 seconds? For a simple `if` statement? No way :) How many `if` statements do you think the typical PHP web page executes?

Comment: if 1. the server is slow. and 2. if the pages that he include also are heavy and use a lot of php than it can be.